# How to create a return values from a list Google Sheet that always adds the new values on the bottom of the list?

Tags: list, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

For a festival production File I'm importing the list of bands from the Programmers File and then I add my needed info behind that. However: the way I now have set it up: it filters the values in either a sorted way or a random way. Which means that when the programmer moves around with rows (drags one above the other, or adds a row in between): that the filter() adds the value (either in its alphabetical place (using Sort() in front of it)  OR returns the exact list/positions). But my info behind the bands I've already dealth with, doesnt change positions of course.. which is a big problem: because then I don't know if the info actually belongs to that band name anymore...

Does anyone know how to get around this? Another formula or extra steps maybe? Can I use Query() and then a Sort By option maybe?
The perfect result would be: that the list just adds the New Value (new band name) on the bottom of the list, no matter where the programmer has put it in his sheet.

My current set-up:
'=FILTER({upper(IMPORTRANGE("[URL]","BANDLIJST!J55:J")),IMPORTRANGE("[URL]","BANDLIJST!C55:C"),IMPORTRANGE("[URL]","BANDLIJST!D55:D"),IMPORTRANGE("[URL]","BANDLIJST!E55:E"),IMPORTRANGE("[URL]","BANDLIJST!f55:f"),IMPORTRANGE("[URL]","BANDLIJST!h55:h"),IMPORTRANGE("[URL]","BANDLIJST!g55:g"),IMPORTRANGE("[URL]","BANDLIJST!i55:i")},IMPORTRANGE("[URL]","BANDLIJST!D55:D")<>"")'

returns the exact list with real positions.
[text](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SDIyZYpdz3v3W6jEjh-VWdujfxOTGjzO3BTS6KnZx38/edit#gid=0)

I've tried unique or sort() but of course those also keep the original problem.. I keep getting all the info perfectly, but it's just too reactive..

Comment: Hi, In order for us to better understand what values we are working with can you give me access to your Google Sheet?